# Lifetime of a temporary file in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, temporary-files

I created a file in asp.net temporary folder.
How long this file will be available in the temporary dir?

Comment: as long as the temp folder exists, I don't recall any expiration policy

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do files created with Path.GetTempFileName get cleaned up automatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9201360/do-files-created-with-path-gettempfilename-get-cleaned-up-automatically)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file is deemed temporary only through its 'tmp' extension and and it's placement in the temporary folder for the user. Such files are **not deleted by the OS**.

See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettempfilename(v=vs.110).aspx