# Where to store temporary files using a windows forms application

Tags: c#, .net, download

I have an application that downloads a file from FTP, reads the file, then deletes it (i download a temporary file because the stream gets disposed before i read the end of the data and i get an exception) and I was wondering what is the programming convention for storing temporary files?  Basically right now I just download the file to the desktop directory (testing phase still) so it pops up on the desktop for a second while it's read then deleted.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/324045/windows-temporary-files-behaviour-are-they-deleted-by-the-system) SO Q & A may be of value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName()` to get a randomly named file in the system's temp directory. Download to there.

Be sure to use `System.IO.File.Delete()` when you're done with it!

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettempfilename%28v=vs.110%29.aspx