# What's the use of TempFileCollection.AddExtension if it doesn't return unique names?

Tags: c#, .net, file, msdn

I need to create three temporary XML files for debugging purposes. I'm using a TempFileCollection as it fits the bill, but apparently the `AddExtension` method doesn't actually return unique file names.

According [to the MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/68yd12wb(v=vs.110).aspx):

> This method can be called only once for each file name extension, because it will return the same name if it is called with the same extension.

Apparently I just have to add my own files anyway using the `AddFile` method. What's the use of this method then? To work around it I'm just using

```
var filename = Guid.NewGuid().ToString + ".xml"
collection.AddFile(filename, false);
```

Comment: careful! `Guid` isn't *guaranteed* to be unique. (although it's very unlikely that it won't be).

Comment: Indeed, but for the rare debugging session I'm doing on this project security isn't an issue and files are removed at the end of the session anyhow.

Answer (score 1):

Per [TempFileCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.CodeDom.Compiler.TempFileCollection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) doc in MSDN:

> To generate a unique name for a temporary file of a **particular** file extension, call AddExtension and specifiy the extension of the file name to generate. The AddExtension method will return a string consisting of a full path to a file name of the specified extension in the directory specified by the TempDir property. The AddExtension method will only return one unique file name **per file name extension**.

TempFileCollection is in `System.CodeDom.Compiler` namespace. If you just want to create some temp files, use [Path.GetTempFileName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettempfilename%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
Console.WriteLine(Path.ChangeExtension(Path.GetTempFileName(), "xml"));
Console.WriteLine(Path.ChangeExtension(Path.GetTempFileName(), "xml"));
Console.WriteLine(Path.ChangeExtension(Path.GetTempFileName(), "xml"));
// You got three different files with .xml extension.
```

Files created by `Path.GetTempFileName()` will NOT be delete automatically. To clean up temp files automatically, use [System.IO.FileOptions.DeleteOnClose](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileoptions.aspx). See similar question at [Windows temporary files behaviour - are they deleted by the system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/324045/windows-temporary-files-behaviour-are-they-deleted-by-the-system). A piece of sample code is like this

```
var path = Path.GetTempFileName();
Console.WriteLine(path);
using (var fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite, 4000, 
    FileOptions.DeleteOnClose))
{
    fs.WriteByte(65);
}
```

I know it's silly to include other unrelated parameters, but it's how this API designed. You can wrap `fs` in other steam or pass it to `XDocument/XElement.Save()`

```
var e = new XElement("Node");
e.Save(fs);
```

Comment: I'm using the TempFileCollection object simply because it does what I need: clean up temp files automatically when done with them. Why rewrite things when someone else already handled it? My question is specifically asking for the utility of such a method. The signature of the method (input an extension, whether to keep the file, and get back a file name) seems to imply that it's generating a new file for you each time. As it turns out it'll only create one unique file and keep returning that. Doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: @MrDoom, If you want them to be deleted automatically, use `System.IO.FileOptions.DeleteOnClose`. See more at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/324045/windows-temporary-files-behaviour-are-they-deleted-by-the-system.

Answer (score 0):

The TempFileCollection is not meant to create temporary **fileNames** for you, it will hold only the temporary files and will delete them upon request in Delete() or when the collection is disposed. See a.o. property KeepFiles.

To generate unique filenames use System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName and System.IO.Path.changeExtension

Comment: But it apparently will, as the first call to AddExtension *will* return a uniquely named file. The second call onwards just returns the same file though. I understand I need to perform external steps to do it myself, however what is the purpose of AddExtension at that point? Some form of pooling?

Answer (score 0):

`TempFileCollection` is in `System.CodeDom.Compiler` namespace.  This implies it is there for the compiler to use.

Based on that, I can view two different use cases for `TempFileCollection`:

- Creating a set of unrelated temp files, and ensuring they are cleaned up after.
- Creating a set of *related* files with different extensions, and ensuring they are cleaned up after.

For the 2nd item (related files), just look at the `bin` and `obj` folders.  You might have multiple files that correspond to the same file.  For example:

- `Program.exe`
- `Program.exe.config`
- `Program.pdb`

So, I would create a single `TempFileCollection` for all of the files that relate to `Program`.  Then, I can call `AddExtension` to get the temp file for the `.exe` file.  I don't need to store that path in a variable - I can just call `AddExtension` again, to get the same path.

TL;DR:

- Use `AddFile` for the first use case (unrelated temp file)
- Use `AddExtension` for the second use case (related temp files, all with unique extensions)